# Фидбэк на landing page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, crm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким способом можно реализовать обратный звонок на landing page?

Comment: `Нога назад`. Зависит от степени реализации, многие системы используют обратный прозвон, тоесть одновременно звонят и клиенту и в офис. Тут гуглите эти системы. Если хотите просто отправить форму, то ставьте какой-нибудь плагин, думаю их сотни

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно это сторонние сервисы. Есть компания, которая предоставляет услуги колл центра. Вы берете их скрипт, добавляете себе на сайт. И все ( [стандартный поисковый запрос](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82&lr=2&clid=2270455&win=335) ) разумеется, это платно

Второй вариант, сами пишете форму, которая отправляет запрос на сервер, там формируется письмо/тикет/уведомление, которое отправляется на почту сотруднику колл-центра/вам лично/кому-то еще, кто отреагирует